# How to remove namespaces and format an XML to excel in the same XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

Hi I am new to XML and XSLT, i have a specific problem to solve in my business.
I get some xml file from a machine with some values. I wish to use XSLT to transform said xml to get relevant information as a excel sheet output.

I have used XSLT 2.0 with xpath to get the relevant information as of now.
The problem is, that for the solution to work, I have to remove some namespace attributes from the root element.

#### Here is the start of my xml data file which i get from the machine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SaData Version="2" xsi:schemaLocation="uuid:ee2fbfd9-47a5-4dc8-a9eb-42d9995802ab SaData.xsd" xmlns="uuid:ee2fbfd9-47a5-4dc8-a9eb-42d9995802ab" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ClientInfo>
    <FirstName>Standalone</FirstName>
    <LastName>
    </LastName>
    <BirthDate>1976-01-01</BirthDate>
    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
    <Gender>Unknown</Gender>
    <Address1>
    </Address1>
    <Address2>
    </Address2>
    <City>
    </City>
    <ZipCode>
    </ZipCode>
    <County>
    </County>
    <Telephone1>
    </Telephone1>
    <Telephone2>
    </Telephone2>
    <PersonNumber>
    </PersonNumber>
    <Guid>2c2bd79e-997b-4061-a386-8d13000748d7</Guid>
    <Properties />
  </ClientInfo>
  <Session>
    <Platform FirmwareVersion="">
    </Platform>
    <Created>2020-08-01T09:37:21</Created>
    <Changed>2020-08-01T09:37:21</Changed>
```

#### SaData is the root node and has 3 namespaces

```
xsi:schemaLocation="uuid:ee2fbfd9-47a5-4dc8-a9eb-42d9995802ab SaData.xsd" 
xmlns="uuid:ee2fbfd9-47a5-4dc8-a9eb-42d9995802ab" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

which i need to remove in order my xls to work, i.e make it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SaData Version="2">
  <ClientInfo>
    <FirstName>Standalone</FirstName>
    <LastName>
    </LastName>
    <BirthDate>1976-01-01</BirthDate>
    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
    <Gender>Unknown</Gender>
    <Address1>
    </Address1>
    <Address2>
    </Address2>
etc.
```

#### Then using stylesheet, lets call it **xml_to_excel.xsl** , partly shown here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/SaData">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="header" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana" ss:Bold="1" />
                </Style>
                
                
                <Style ss:ID="createdformat">
                    <NumberFormat ss:Format="General Date"/>
                </Style>
            </Styles>
            <Worksheet ss:Name="Affinity">
                <Table>
                    
                    
                    <Row ss:Index="1">
                        
                        <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="header">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">S.No.</Data>
```

I get my excel compatible xml file using a saxon based app, called Kernow, https://andrewjwelch.com/kpro/

### What i have done now

Using other stackoverflow answers i was able to somewhat remove the need to manually remove these name spaces, **by using an intermediary xsl stylesheet** , which simply removes all namespaces and keeps rest of xml as is. This xls file, called **removenamespace.xsl** is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*[name() = 'xsi:schemaLocation']"/>
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='xsi:type')]|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output, lets call it **cleanrecords.xml** is the intermediary xml file without namespaces.

I then use this cleanrecords.xml with my xml_to_excel.xsl stylesheet to get  final result which is the desired excel file.

### Now for the question: How can i combine these 2 stylesheets into one so i don't need to do this series of transformations and directly get the excel file using one stylesheet instead

Comment: 1. Please post a [mcve]. 2. I think all you need to do is add an `xpath-default-namespace` attribute to your 2nd stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k! it worked with default namespace. and dorry about the long question

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to combine two transformations into one there are several approaches possible:

(a) Link them using some calling framework such as XProc, Ant, Gradle, a Java application, a shell script, or a host of other solutions. You can even use XSLT for this: have a stylesheet that invokes two separate transformations using the `fn:transform()` function in XSLT 3.0.

(b) Combine them into a single stylesheet using the coding pattern

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp" mode="phase2"/>
```

(It's best to use separate modes to keep the phases disjoint.)

But in this case, the preprocessing phase to strip namespaces is really unnecessary. It's perfectly easy to make your main transformation handle namespaced XML input, for example by using the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! It worked by adding  xpath-default-namespace="uuid:..." to my 2nd xsl